# "compile project" is not available in Word 2010 VBA editor

Tags: vba, compilation, ms-word

I have a MS Word template (.dot file), and sometimes the Debug->Compile option is available, and sometimes it isn't. Why? And why should I want to compile my VBA at all?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you compile your project (or run a Sub, which automatically compiles the project before running) then the Compile item disappears, since the project is already compiled. As soon as you edit your VBA code, the Compile item will reappear in the Debug menu.

It behaves a bit like the "Save" item in the File menu of some applications e.g. certain text editors. If the file has not changed since it was last saved, then the "Save" item is grayed out.

As for why you would want to compile: it's a good way to test for compile-time errors, without having your code actually run. If you just run it, then it will compile and then proceed to execute if there are no compile-time errors. You may not want this to happen if e.g. your code sends e-mail around, modifies your document, deletes files, or whatever.

Comment: Additionally, if you run code without compiling it first, only the procedures that are run are compiled. So if you have an error in a procedure that doesn't get run, you will still have the compile option available in the debug menu.